# Will cypress support Edge Html browsers

Tags: cypress

My application will support only on EdgeHtml browser.

Can you please confirm me, will cypress support EdgeHtml browser?

Regards,
Jagan

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does support edge browser.
You can see it in the Features section under 'Supported Browsers'.

Since Edge is based on Chromium, this is basically just another Chrome.